# Parameters handling in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Currently I'm reading JavaScript book. There is a code snippet in it which I can't understand. What's happening in the line  `repeat(3, function(n) {`? Why we can pass parameter `n` to the second argument of the function `repeat`, because in its declaration there is nothing about passing parameters? How does `repeat` understand that it should pass parameter `n` to the `unless` function?

```
function unless(test, then) {
    if (!test) then();
}
function repeat(times, body) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}
repeat(3, function(n) {
    unless(n % 2, function() {
        console.log(n, "is even");
    });
});
// → 0 is even
// → 2 is even
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why we can pass parameter n to the second argument of the function repeat, because in its declaration there is nothing about passing parameters

You are **not** passing `n` as the second argument to `repeat()`, you are passing an [anonymous function](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/) that takes a single parameter and you chose to name **its** parameter `n` (so parameter of the function that is passed in)

Functions in JavaScript are, in simple words, just objects that can also be executed. This means you can pass functions around as parameters to other functions, or add properties to them like you would to objects, etc.

Here's an illustration of what is happening in your example:

Function `repeat` is defined with two arguments:

```
repeat(times, body)
```

So, all you are doing is **passing a `function` as the `body` argument**.
Writing it like this is equivalent:

```
var times = 3;
var body = function(n) {
    unless(n % 2, function() {
        console.log(n, "is even");
    });
};

repeat(time, body);
```

> How does repeat understand that it should pass parameter n to the unless function?

As you can see above, `repeat` is not passing anything to `unless()`.
It is your anonymous function (stored in `body` in my example above) that is actually passing `n` to `unless`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing a parameter `n` at all.

In reality, you're passing an entire anonymous function as a parameter (functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript and can be passed around just like other variables).

If you look, the function is passed as the `body` parameter to the method `repeat`. `repeat` then calls the function `body` with the parameter of `i`...which is the parameter `n` in the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to write a function to repeat x number of times, and check if it's even, you'd probably want to do it like this:

```js
function repeat(times) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        output.innerHTML+= is_even(i)+"\n";
    }
}
function is_even(n) {
   if ( n % 2 ) return n+" is even";
   return n+" is odd";
}
var output = document.getElementById('output');
repeat(6); // Output variable wasn't passed to this function, we're using it globally
```

```html
<pre id='output'></pre>
```